# How can I add or change data in the report generated by maven-surefire?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to create a reporting feature for my work application for my boss. I'm using the maven-surefire and maven-surefire-report plugins to create it. So far, I've been able to produce the .txt, .xml, and the .html files. I'm seeing a few things that I'd like to change tho:

1. I'd like more information in the HTML report.  Ex. I'd like to be able to add log messages (log4j) and have the assertions as well as ONLY the log messages display in the report. I currently have `<redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>` which works but it's only adding info to the .txt and I'd like to try and keep out all the non-test fluff. I read that you can create a custom log4j.properties file but couldn't find much more on what it would look like.
2. I'm seeing something weird where the report is counting test failures as their own test instead of test steps. I.e. I have 1 test with multiple assertions (boss wanted it this way) and instead of reporting this 1 test has multiple failures, it is just showing every failure as its own test. I'm using the **ErrorCollector** to do this. I just wrapped that class to make one that works specifically for me.

I wasn't sure if I should include any actual code snippets here so please let me know if you guys need more information. Thanks SO!

Comment: Does maven-surefire use anything that isn't shown in the raw test output? You might be able to direct your logger to print to stdout and capture that as test output. A quick experiment might be to add a System.out.println call and see if that output is in your report

Comment: Regarding item 2 - Maybe you should leave that as it is. It is an example of WHY tests should only assert once

Comment: @Freiheit regarding your first comment - I do have some sout statements and they do, in fact, get displayed in the text version of the report. The problem is that every other single thing that gets displayed in the console is also put into the report so it's really messy.

For your 2nd comment - I agree but I'm sure you've had a boss that was very insistent on something. Would you, personally, separate a test into tens (probably 30ish) separate assertion tests? Right now I'm just pulling data from a DB using spring-boot and asserting that it's what I think it should be. Nothing too heavy.

Comment: Since sout is displayed you might have a path to a solution. Can you redirect your logger to sout *and* set the logging level such that you only get the output you need?